# Delphi- Passing parameters to ADOquery

Tags: delphi, ado, parameter-passing

Dear experts,
I’m trying to filter the result in dbgrid connected to adoquery, depending on user selection of 4 checkboxes, user can select one or more fileds to filter the data accordingly
I have this code, and I don’t know how to pass "and/ or not pass" it if user select two or more checkboxes.

```
Vw_Activity.SQL.Text:='select * from Vw_Activity where ';
if CBEmployee.Checked then
begin
Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('Emp_Name_Ar=:x');
Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('x').Value:=emp Name.Text;
end;


if CBTask.Checked then
begin
Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('Category_Name=:y');
Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('y').Value:=Pro blemCat.Text;
end;

if CBIncharge.Checked then
begin
Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('Support_name_En=:h');
Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('h').Value:=Sup portstaff.Text;
end;


if CBstatus.Checked then
begin
Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('Request_Status=:k');
Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('k').Value:=Req uestStatus.Text;
end;

Vw_Activity.Active:=true;
```

waitting your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can rewrite your sql sentence to (check the final 1=1)

```
select * from Vw_Activity where 1=1
```

and then add each condition like this

```
Vw_Activity.SQL.Text:='select * from Vw_Activity where 1=1 ';
if CBEmployee.Checked then
begin
  Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('AND Emp_Name_Ar=:x');
  Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('x').Value:=emp Name.Text;
end;


if CBTask.Checked then
begin
  Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('AND Category_Name=:y');
  Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('y').Value:=Pro blemCat.Text;
end;

if CBIncharge.Checked then
begin
  Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('AND Support_name_En=:h');
  Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('h').Value:=Sup portstaff.Text;
end;


if CBstatus.Checked then
begin
  Vw_Activity.SQL.Add('AND Request_Status=:k');
  Vw_Activity.Parameters.ParamByName('k').Value:=Req uestStatus.Text;
end;

Vw_Activity.Active:=true;
```